# Select all text in a textbox Selenium RC using Ctrl + A

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to select all the text in a textbox in order to clear the textbox. I am using Ctrl+A to do this using the following Python 2.7 code on Selenium RC standalone 2.20.0.jar Server on Windows 7 firefox:

```
from selenium import selenium
s = selenium('remote-machine-ip', 4444, '*chrome', 'http://my-website-with-textbox')
locator = 'mylocator-of-textbox'
s.open()
s.type(locator, 'mytext')
s.focus(locator)
s.control_key_down()
s.key_down(locator, "A")
s.key_press(locator, "A")
s.key_up(locator, "A")
s.control_key_up()

# Nothing happens here... I cannot see the text getting selected...

# Nothing gets cleared here except the last char
s.key_down(locator, chr(8))  # Pressing backspace
s.key_press(locator, chr(8))
s.key_up(locator, chr(8))
```

Any help?
Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 11):

I'm using clear() in WebDriver without any hassle...

```
el = self.selenium.find_element_by_name(name)
el.clear()
```

Comment: I am not using WebDriver, because I am using Selenium RC... Any idea how to do the same in Selenium RC... I don't want to move to WebDriver now...

Comment: If .clear is not present in RC (I think it is), how about `.type("")` ?

Comment: I tried .type("A") in place of .key_down/press/up().... But I get the following exception:
type not supported immediately after call to controlKeyDown() or altKeyDown() or metaKeyDown()

Comment: In my case clearing the textbox didn't help because the website automatically re-enters 0,00 if the textfield is cleared. While this might have been what op needed, this is not what he asked in the question title.

Answer (score 0):

In Selenium RC, simply use the following to clear a textbox

> selenium.type("someLocator", "");

Answer (score 0):

Try using first

```
element.click()
```

then use element

```
element.clear()
```

It might solve your issue as it really solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
 public void selectAll(WebElement element) {
    String selectAll = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a");
    element.sendKeys(selectAll);
}
```

And when you whant to use it, for example:

```
    selectAll(myDriver.findElement(By.id("testId")));
```

In this example the WebElement can be a text box, text area and similars.

Comment: This is not Python though. Could you maybe link the documentation so that people can at least understand the code if they can't copy-paste it

Comment: Sure.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/key-press-in-ctrlplusa-selenium-webdriver#:~:text=this%20keyboard%20action.-,The%20Keys.,A%2C%20it%20takes%2C%20Keys.